# How to call a function on clicking a text in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an anchor tag in HTML. I want to create a click event which calls function. The issue is whatever solution I have tried makes the page reload. I don't want the page to reload or refresh.

```
  <div *ngIf="showOTPResendText">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Please wait {{counter | formatTime}} seconds(s) before requesting a new One Time Password(OTP)</p>
  </div>

  <div class="otp-not-recieved">
    <br />
    <h4>
      Not received your code?&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a [routerLink]="/"></a>
      <a href="" onclick="resendOTP()"> Resend OTP.</a>

    </h4>
  </div>
```

The text looks something like this.
[Text Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2niv.jpg).

I want it to be text and still hit a function in typescript which calls the resend otp function.

What I have tried and problem I am facing with the solution.

1. onclick="return false; It doesn't reload the page but then I can't call the function.
2. Thought of using routerlink but then I don't want to route anywhere and if I route to same page it still reloads the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if you want to have a click event but not go anywhere you can also just not use an `<a>` tag but regular `<p>`/`<span>`/... tag as well.

The angular way is to use the click attribute, so something like

```
<span (click)="callToYourFunction()">Text</span>
```

If you really want to use an `<a>` tag I think you should be able to prevent the event default. For example

```
<a (click)="myFunction($event)">Link</a>

function myFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Using the above solutions makes the text unclickable and do not call any function.

Comment: if you set it up properly in a stackblitz i'm glad to help ;)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-otp-input-cwrlsf?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html. I created this stackblitz. However in stackblitz it's working as per my expectations but in actual app where I have multiple component it reloads the page. Any idea why it is happening.

Comment: well just try to reproduce the same setup in stackblitz. hard to tell without knowing your project